# Add Custom TinyMCE Toolbar

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

My aim is to create a tabbed menubar instead of the traditional menubar presented in the latest TinyMCE 4.7.6. I plan to do this by hiding the menubar, then create a toolbar above the normal toolbar. This new toolbar would consist of buttons with the menu names such as File, Edit, Insert, View etc. When one of these buttons is clicked, the normal toolbar buttons would be replaced with the toolbar buttons under the relevant menu item. [I hope I have been clear to this point.]

In case I haven't worded my description well enough, I want to create something like the Microsoft Word 2013 menu style.

Here's my problem. I am unable to create the toolbar that would host the menu buttons (File, Edit etc buttons). The TinyMCE docs say nothing about creating custom toolbars. All there is, is on creating toolbar buttons and adding them to an existing toolbar. Anyone with an idea how this can be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite some work you want to do, so first of all let me tell you a "ribbon" skin is already existing, [check it here](http://tinymce.swis.nl/)

Now if you really want to make your own, first you have to understand the difference between a `menubar` and a `toolbar`

On this image there is one menubar and two toolbars

[image]

Here is [the documentation for the menubar API](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.MenuBar) and for the toolbar [this is here](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.Toolbar)

But you should really give a try to the existing skin first.

Comment: From what I see, this skin was last updated in 2012. I do not know if it is still compatible with the current version of TinyMCE. I actually tried it but TinyMCE never initialized properly. It shows a white screen and nothing. No error message whatsoever.

Comment: Hum actually I never tried this skin so I don't know about such issue. You can also check the documentation on [how to create your own skin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-skin/) and the `Ribbon skin for TinyMCE` source code which seems to be working with TinyMCE 3.4.4 at least. You should have enough resources to dig in.

Comment: Worth trying. Although I'm not sure if what I was looking to create was a whole new skin. I was hoping I could play around with `menubar` and `toolbar` to create a plugin that could convert any skin into the ribbon appearance.